# Массив с потокобезопасными объектами C++

Tags: c++, массивы, многопоточность

Допустим, у меня есть класс Foo

```
class Foo {...}
```

И массив указателей длины N

```
Foo * fooArr[N];
```

Есть несколько потоков, которые должны читать и изменять элементы массива (а могут вообще удалить какой-то элемент)
Первое, что приходит на ум - добавить массив мьютексов
mutex mutArr[N];

И функции void lock(int index); и unlock(int index);
Которые блокировали бы определённый объект на время работы с ним

Но при слишком больших длинах возникает исключение

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N = 25000;

int main() {

    mutex mutArr[N];
    cout << sizeof(mutArr) << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Исключение при большом количестве мьютексов в программе]

1. Могу ли я как-то получить максимальное количество мьютексов в программе?
2. Есть ли альтернативный способ организовать блокировку определённого элемента массива? (потока всего 2-3)

Comment: Вы бы показали код. Потому что переполнение стека может быть вызвано самыми разными причинами...

Comment: Для того что бы организовать корректное изменение массива достаточно же будет и одного мьютекса (просто при обращении к массиву блокировать и все). Если же нужно синхронизировать доступ к определенному объекту массива, то можно как вариант добавить в данный класс его собственный мьютекс и сделать геттеры / сеттеры которые бы использовали мьютекс внутри класса

Comment: Либо массив пометить как `volatile Foo * fooArr[100];`

Comment: @Harry, код очень простой и написан для проверки. Работает при N = 16000. Но я боюсь, что ограничения количества мьютексов могут быть разными на разных системах и где-то могут быть значительно ниже

#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N = 25000;

int main() {

 mutex mutArr[N];
 cout << sizeof(mutArr) << endl;

 system("pause");

 return 0;
}

Comment: Ограничения на число мутексов нет. Однако, мутекс "тяжелый" объект. Т.е. занимает много места. Массив `mutArr[N]`, занимающий более 2 Mb не умещается на стеке. Убедиться в этом можно, заменив массив на динамический ` std::vector<std::mutex> mutArr(N);`.

Либо выделяйте память для массива динамически, либо увеличьте размер стека (в опциях линкера).

Comment: @Chorkov почему не в качестве ответа, а комментарием?

Comment: @goldstar_labs mutex не является объектом ядра, точнее мьютекс из стандартной библиотеки не обязательно работает поверх системного мьютекса. Реализация из студии использует SRWlock

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar Добавление квалификатора volatile не делает объект потокобезопасным. В студии было соответствующее нестандартное расширение, но использовать его не следует.

Comment: @VTT, спасибо не знал